# Update specific table when onUpgrade with SQLite with provided database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

Probably there is somewhere here answer to my question, but if it exist I can't find it.
Here is my problem:
I have provided database in assets folder. When I want to update my app because I put some more rows in specific table I increase db version, call this.getWritableDatabase(); and onUpgrade is called, to this point everything is ok. 
But what next? 
Here is my onUpgrade function:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    if(i < i2) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.execSQL("attach database ? as newdb", new String[]{DB_PATH + DB_NAME}); // I have to attach new version of db to the old one and then i can go on
        db.execSQL("delete from GAME");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GAME SELECT * FROM newdb.GAME");
        db.close();
}
```

This gives me an error that my db is locked - on the line:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO GAME SELECT * FROM newdb.GAME");
```

I tried a lot of different scenarious but I just can't make it.
I'll be very glad if someone could help me make it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your `onUpgrade` does not use its first parameter, it does something wrong.

`db` and `newdb` are the same database (both times opened with `DB_PATH + DB_NAME`).

You probably want to replace `db` with `sqLiteDatabase`.

Comment: Yes, I replaced db with sqLiteDatabase and it gives me npe. sqLiteDatabase variable is simply null (I tried to update it and there is nothing inside).

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` never calls `onUpgrade` will a `null` DB.

Comment: Well, in my case I guess it does. I have standard implementation, when I run app for the first time everything is ok, my database is being copied to internal storage and app works fine. Then, I change db version from 1 to 2 and install app again. onUpgrade is opened and the first line inside is now " sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("delete from GAME"); ". And I have an error " no such table: GAME (code 1): , while compiling: delete from GAME ", so, sqLiteDatabase is null.

Comment: Once again, to be 100% sure. In line public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) { - sqLiteDatabase is my actual database, the old one, yes? So it's not supposed to be null :/

Comment: If `sqLiteDatabase` were `null`, you would have gotten a null pointer exception. "no such table: GAME" means that that table is not there, probably because of a bug in the database creation code. Anyway, the actual question (why the DB is locked) has been answered. If you have a new question, [ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

onUpgrade means that you want to upgrade your database, not to copy some data from old one to new. this method gives you all you need to do upgrade - db instance to roll upgrade scripts for specific version. SQL is very powerful you can add/remove columns, delete tables and so on, so I don't see a reason to make another file.

Comment: I know it means upgrade and this is what I'm trying to do.  And copying data from old one to new is in this case upgrade. I think you don't understand me well. I don't want to make another file, I simply provide to my app manualy prepared database with a lot of rows.

Comment: In this case you didn't understand what I'm trying to tell you. To upgrade you should create SQL statements to change your db schema to match your new db schema and then roll all the data with SQL.